# ASP.NET Custom Server Control not refreshing in designer

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, designer, custom-server-controls

I have a written an ASP.NET Custom Server Control, which I have working. This control inherits from `CompositeControl` and has different views that it can show during its life time. The best analogy would be similar to a Tab control where one control has many user selectable views depending on which tab the user selected. Before someone asks, no, mine is not a Tab control, it's an analogy that everyone should be familiar with.

Anyway, I want to have the view to be selectable in the Visual Studio 2010 designer. To do this, I created a `CompositeControlDesigner` with actions (just a single combobox to select the view). All of this works just fine, I have even stepped through the code in the debugger and verified that everything is firing off as expected including `CreateChildControls` back in the main control, but Visual Studio is NOT refreshing the screen. It only appears to refresh the designer if a tag is added/removed/modified on the control (which will not happen in this case since it is an designer-only feature)

Does anyone have a clue as to how to force the designer to refresh?

Comment: Have you looked through this tutorial?: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12yydcke.aspx

Comment: @James, yes, I have.  While that tutorial uses a designer _object_, all it does is set something statically for the control (never allowing it to be resized, in this case). I need something dynamic. The next tutorial down (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey0f414) is what I based my code upon, which gives the designer a visual element, but that example is manipulating properties on the control (thus works) and my is only trying to manipulate something in the designer. Thanks though.